# Keyboard layout related issue

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard

I run on Ubuntu 14.04. I have an issue related to the keyboard layout in GUI mode. I managed to fix it in the GUI by using: setxkbmap -layout us [1] and adding it to the ~/.bashrc. That works fine. However, the problem is that when I log to the text-mode terminal I receive an error - Cannot display "default display". This is not surprising because this command does not work in text mode. The question is: where should I put [1] and have no error in text mode terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is solved. Added script to `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [ "$TERM" = "xterm" ]; then 
   setxkbmap -layout "us"
fi
```